# in R, eval is not evaluating in the correct environment

Tags: r, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
z <- 1
a <- function() {
  print(parent.frame())
  eval(quote({print(z)}))
}
b <- function() {
  z <- 2
  print(environment())
  a()
}
b()
# output:
<environment: 0x55f0020b1af0>
<environment: 0x55f0020b1af0>
[1] 1
```

According to documentation:

```r
Usage

eval(expr, envir = parent.frame(),
           enclos = if(is.list(envir) || is.pairlist(envir))
                       parent.frame() else baseenv())
```

Since the `envir` argument defaults to `parent.frame()`, which is the environment of function `b`, it is the `z` inside of `b` that is supposed to be printed. But rather it is the `z` in the global environment that is printed.

Comment: Note that default parameters are evaluated in the running function environment but parameters you pass in are evaluated in the calling environment. So you get a very different `parent.frame()` if you pass it in as a parameter vs if you use the default value. Try `evalq(print(z), envir=parent.frame())` instead of the `eval()` you currently have.

Answer (score 3):

The parent frame of `eval` is the caller of `eval`, not the caller of `a`.

```
# same as eval except for addition of print statement
my.eval <- function (expr, envir = parent.frame(), enclos = if (is.list(envir) || 
    is.pairlist(envir)) parent.frame() else baseenv())  {
  print(envir)
  .Internal(eval(expr, envir, enclos))
}

z <- 1
a <- function() {
  print(environment())
  my.eval(quote({print(z)}))
}

b <- function() {
  z <- 2
  a()
}
b()
## <environment: 0x000000000b208d20>
## <environment: 0x000000000b208d20>
```